# How to pass an object as an argument using a React onClick event?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary, object

I have an array of objects, and I rendered the names from it. What I would like to do is when I click on them, I get the exact object that contains the name I clicked on, and then render those other data out.

```
export default function App() {

  const array = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'John',
      num: '0123'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Dave',
      num: '456'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Bruce',
      num: '789'
    },
  ]

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {array.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <p onClick={handleClick}>{item.name}</p>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

1. add to function handleSelect(userID) with argument userID:

```
  const handleSelect = (userId) => {
    const currentUser = array.filter(item => item.id === userId)[0]
    console.log(currentUser) // or return
  }
```

2. Add onClick event to div or p

```
    <div className="App">
      {array.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <p onClick={() => handleSelect(item.id)}>{item.name}</p>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do:

```
const handleClick = (id, name, num) => {
    console.log(`id=${id}, name=${name}, num=${num} `);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {array.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <p onClick={()=>handleClick(item.id, item.name, item.num)}>{item.name}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

Here is a codesandbox link: [for the above](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-shtern-jclvn?file=/src/App.js:0-635)

Ofcourse, you can try to re-access the object. Check this out:

```
const handleClick = (id, name, num) => {
    console.log(`Easy way : id=${id}, name=${name}, num=${num} `);

    //Re-access the object. But why? 
    const desiredObjArr = array.filter(obj=> obj.id=id);
    console.log(`I get this in a tough way: ${desiredObjArr[0].name}, ${desiredObjArr[0].id}, ${desiredObjArr[0].num}`);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Give some `data-*` attribute to the clicked element.
2. Find the item by id.
3. Do not use the index as a key in React. Use unique id.
4. Wrap functions inside `React.useCallback`.

```
export default function App() {
  const array = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'John',
      num: '0123'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Dave',
      num: '456'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Bruce',
      num: '789'
    },
  ]

  const handleClick = React.useCallback((e) => {
    const clickedId = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
    const item = array.find(({ id }) => id === clickedId);
    console.log(item);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {array.map((item) => {
        return (
          <div key={item.id}>
            <p data-id={item.id} onClick={handleClick}>{item.name}</p>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The temptation is to treat the React onClick as if it was the same as an onclick attribute in an html tag. But while in the latter you would then call the function you want to execute along with it's argument (say, like so: <p onclick="handleClick(item)", in the former you wrap the function you are calling in another anonymous function. Following those strictures, to make your own code work as you want it to, you only have to revise it slightly like so:

```
  const handleClick = (item) => {
    console.log(item.id, item.name, item.num)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {array.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <p onClick={()=>{handleClick(item)}}>{item.name}</p>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

Here's a working Stackblitz:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6ywm5v